# Chrome Refuses to Print with bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I have been scouring the internet for this one, I have a project at work that uses Bootstrap 2.3.2 for styling. All is good but when we try and print the page. Chrome and only chrome refuses to print with the boot strap styles.

Just for fun i have tried the new bootstrap 3.0.3 css files and they won't print properly in chrome either.

Has anyone encountered an issue where it prints or gives a proper print preview in ie and Firefox but not in chrome when it comes to bootstrap?

Comment: Do the non-Bootstrap styles print?

Comment: Yes a coworker solved the issue by copying some of the bootstrap.css into our own css page into a @media print query. I don't know the exact details though so that's why i'm not marking it in the answer.
Yes the non bootstrap styles where fine. it was between bootstrap and chrome.